# How to efficiently calculate fractions in R contingency table?

Tags: r

I have a contingency table in R:

```
> k
     rank
admit  1  2  3  4
    0 28 97 93 55
    1 33 54 28 12
```

Is there a smart way to calculate the fractions by rank? I.e. fraction of admit = 0 for rank 1 = 28/(28+33)?